# How to change the dimension of the axis in altair plots?

Tags: python, altair

I am displaying a combined case diagram for a single side for three fields. But the values on the axis are too large. There are extra zeros. How to remove them? The peak value should not be 18,000,000, but 18,000

Code

```
elif type_of_plots_country == 'Комбинированная диаграмма':

    country_graph = alt.Chart(world_data).transform_fold(
        ["confirmed", "deaths", "recovered"],
        as_=["field", "value"]
    ).mark_bar(size=20).encode(
        x=alt.X("field:N", title=''),
        y=alt.Y("sum(value):Q", stack=None, title='Количество'),
        column="country:N"
    ).properties(
        width=alt.Step(100)
    ).configure_axis(
        labelFontSize=17,
        titleFontSize=15
    )
```

Plot`s

[image]

Comment: You could use pandas or Altair's `transform_calculate` to divide a column by 1000, but before modifying anything here you should look into why the values are too large. Is the data you are using incorrectly entered? Or are there additional groups in the data that you need to filter by in order not to count some entries multiple times?

Comment: @joelostblom This does not happen with other charts. Everything works stably. Can't tell you how to use "transform_calculate"?

Comment: Can you upload a sample of your `world_data` dataframe to reproduce the problem? I think it is important to understand why this happens.